# how to add message to toString() in main method

Tags: java, tostring, superclass

I have a superclass, a subclass and a implementation class. I overrode the toString in the subclass, and I have an array in main method. my question was if I have to add static variable from subclass at the end, how should I override the toString() in the main method.

in super class,

```
public String toString(){
   return "This is my message";
}
```

in subclass,

```
private static int num;

public String toString(){
return super.toString()+ "\na Message from subclass";
```

}

in main method,

```
MySubClass myVariable=new MySubClass();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,myVariable + "\nFinal message" + MySubClass.getNum());
```

this keeps giving me an error message.
so I tried,

```
String message = myVariable + "\nFinal message";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message);
```

this didnt work either.
what should I do to add final message to toString()?

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with `toString()`. What do you mean by `"add final message to toString()?"` And if you're getting errors, you might want to show the error messages to us. Sorry, but yours is a very confusing question. Please ask it as if you are in our shoes, folks who know nothing of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
you need to specify where is the problem (is it compile time error?)

if you have superclass with toString and want in child class to append another message on child toString(), you will override toString() and call your superclass method:

```
public class Child extends SuperClass {
  @Override
  public toString() {
     return super.toString() + " your child message";
  }
}
```

now can call your child.toString() to get the message

if this is not what your problem, please describe it clearly.

Comment: +1 yes you correct, it will done automaticly without toString

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have superclass, subclass and a implementation class. I overrode the toString in subclass, and I have an array in the implementation class. my question was if I have to add static variable from subclass at the end, how should I override the toString() in the implementation class.

Comment: what do you mean by implementation class, can you edit your question and edit the code also?

Comment: I mean in the main method

Comment: why do want to override toString in your main method or implementation class? also why you want to add static variable in your subclass what the purpose of it?

Comment: because the message must have all the information of the array and I have to add total number of the array elements at the end of the message.